# Why my XPath and HTML scraping stopped working in Google Sheets?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-finance

My XPath queries used to work fine, however, about a month ago (or when Nasdaq moved to a new website. I have to use the old.nasdaq.com since), the just started working irregularly. As you may see on the attached screen, some work, others don't, and they take turns.

The ones that give me a headache are supposed to grab the last 4 unique dividend paying months from the dividend history and display them in a row for further processing.

The query for dividend history months looks as following ($B2 is a ticker, e.g. AAPL):

```
=iferror(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(sort(text(query(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://old.nasdaq.com/symbol/",$B2,"/dividend-history"),"//tbody//tr[1] | //tbody//tr[2] | //tbody//tr[3] | //tbody//tr[4]"),"select Col6 limit 4"),"mmm"),1,1))))
```

The Industry query is acting the same way. Here is the formula:

```
=(importxml(CONCATENATE("https://old.nasdaq.com/symbol/",B4),"//*[@id='qbar_sectorLabel']/a"))
```

[image]

Am I using the wrong approach? If there are better and more reliable statistic providers than Nasdaq, I'd like to hear about them too. Also, I'd like to keep things simple (i.e. no scripting, only G-sheets formulas).

**Update:** Same happening with the Html scraping from the proposed answer. After 2 days the outcome started randomly disappearing, same as the XPath scraping.

Comment: dates you are scraping are not valid dates. they need to be converted first to valid ones otherwise IFERROR will just nullify them out

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TEXT(DATE(2000, 
 SORT(1*REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://old.nasdaq.com/symbol/"&B2&"/dividend-history", "table", 3)), 
 "select Col6 limit 4 offset 1", 0), "^\d+")), 1), "MMM")))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It worked at first but after some time the "disappearing" pattern repeated.
Also, I couldn't make it to work with the Industry field.